# Batch file not working on other computer

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

I wrote a batch file that takes user input and adds it to html then outputs a text file with the combined information to post to craigslist. It's all pretty simple and works great on my computer but when I try to run it on other computers it won't output the file. I used

```
(
echo sdfg
echo argare
echo asgfa
)>%filename%.txt
```

to put it into the file.
My computer is a windows XP and I've tried it on another XP and vista machine and neither one works.
Any help would be appreciated as I spent about 2-3 weeks on this and I'd hate to see it go to waste.

I figured out what was wrong but I still have a question, one of the inputs is a phone number and the salesperson put () around the area code for his phone number. Now my question is why did that interfere and how do I stop it from happening again?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the script?  We'd need to know what the value of %filename% is.

Comment: I can't post all of it as it's to much but the end part is this:
)>ads\%stock%.txt
Echo the templete is done. :)
pause
I'd also like to say that the pause doesn't pause it and wait for a key to be hit.

Comment: Also is there a way to format the code in a comment on here? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @Preston - Sort of. It only works like `this`, you just surround it with the backquote, "`". Click on the help link for more help.

Comment: @Preston - The short answer to you question is that `(` and `)` are special characters. I can't be more specific without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are not looking in the correct place, or filename is not defined properly. The file will be crated in a folder relative to the current directory unless filename is defined as an absolute path.

Add some diagnostic lines to help you track down what is happening.

```
(
  echo sdfg
  echo argare
  echo asgfa
)>%filename%.txt
echo CD=%CD%
echo filename=%filename%
```

Comment: I don't think that would work as I had just mentioned above there is a pause command after the output that also doesn't run so I feel like something is shutting it down when it tries to output.

Comment: Move the diagnostics before where you think it is shutting down.